# How i get backing dataset name with phonograph id?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-phonograph

I have a Phonograph table id. How can I know what is the backing dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Phonograph service API through Slate, you should be able to use the **Get Table Metadata** endpoint from the **Table Registry Service**. This endpoint takes in the Table RID and returns the schema and sync metadata, including the RID of the source dataset.

If you're not using these endpoints through Slate, but rather through a CLI or 3rd-party application, you can find the full Phonograph API definition in the platform documentation under the **Developer** tab.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this Phonograph table is used to write to an ontology object type, you can go into the Ontology Management Application and paste the id into the object type search field on the top left (see screenshot).
This will automatically find the related object type. If you select that object type and then click on the Datasources tab, you will see the corresponding backing dataset.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Table is not using ontology layer.Is there is any other way to find out?

Comment: @Sunil you have a phonograph index that does not show in the ontology management app?